# sequence to sequence models output

Tags: tensorflow

I executed the code translate.py from sequence to sequence models tutorial of tensorflow 60 hours ago and still waiting for the output.
Can anyone tell me how much more time will it take to display the output
System specifications:
I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware with a disk space of 35 GB and RAM of 1 GB.

Comment: Is this on GPU? What is `nvidia-smi` saying? Is the process still running?

Comment: NOT GPU. Yes, the process is still running and I haven't got any output yet

Comment: You should start the script with `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)`, then it should print out more.

Comment: Do  I need to insert the line"tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)" in my translate.py code?

Comment: Somewhere before you start the session. You can just set it first thing in main.

Comment: Yes. I inserted it in the first line of def main: and got so many errors. Can you please give ur email id so that i will send u the errors screenshot

Comment: That line should work after you have imported tensorflow.  There will be a lot more output. Please put it on pastebin and provide a link so I can take a look.

Comment: Yes i did. I was waiting for output since an hour. It is eating space. I dont know how to delete if anything was downloaded to save space. I extended my disk space to 100 GB as it gave me many errors saying "unexpected end of data". Now, I am worried it may eat the space again. Can you please tell me the folder to delete the previously downloaded data

Answer (score 0):

The best way is check the code . Normally in the training phase we don't print the progress in every epoch .  So it might take some time .

Any way you should see in the following info in the terminal

1. May be something model creation .
2. Some GPU details when starting a session .

So as soon as session started it should print GPU details like , 
How many GPUs , available memory etc . And some configuration details also . Normally for that it won't take much time .

**Soon after model creation you should able to see something. Maximum with in 10 .(If your machine is really really slow)**

I think there's an error in your implementation !